# A battery session meaning?

Tags: android, battery, android-vitals

I am confused by the definition provide by google: **A battery session refers to the interval between two full battery charges**.

For example your battery is 1000mAh, a fully charge means you charge it to its full capacity regardless of the initial amount in the battery or the total amount charged into the battery equal 1000mAh

Comment: if you charged your battery 100% yesterday and today you charge it again to 100% then better session is one day regardless of mAh

Comment: This question has been answered quite detailed [in this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138401/android-definition-of-charge-cycle)

Comment: @TejasPandya what if i only used 10% of my battery and charge it again?

Comment: @QuangNhat after charge upto 100% battery status will be reset by system and no all battery usage states by an application will be reset automatically